# Using Multer to handle formdata

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer

I have this code that creates a `project` and uploads the image to Amazon S3.

I am using `Bodyparser` middleware to handle the data coming from the client but after some research I found out that it doesn't handle `formdata`. I need to use `multer` or some library like that.

Here is my attempt to use multer:

In my routes folder that handles the `Post` request to the `Create` function, I added it like this:

```
import multer from 'multer';
const upload = multer(); 
routes.post(
  '/',
  upload.any('projectImage'),
  ProjectController.create,
);
```

Here is the `Create` function:

```
export async function create(req, res, next) {
  const body = req.body;
  S3Upload(req, res, async (s3err, s3res) => {
    if (s3err) {
      res.send('Error occured uploading image')
    } else if (s3res && s3res.Location) {
      body.projectImage = s3res.Location
      try {
        return res
          .status(HTTPStatus.CREATED)
          .json(await Project.createProject(body, req.user._id));
      } catch (err) {
        err.status = HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        return next(err);
      }
    } else {
      res.send('Error creating project.')
    }
  });
}
```

Now when I send a post request to the `/project` routes. I get this error:

```
(node:77236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (0 , _s2.default) is not a function

(node:77236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

PS. The `Create` function works perfectly without adding the S3Upload. & the S3Upload also works perfectly if I am only sending a file. The only time when it doesnt work is when I send mix data. i.e. a form with some text fields and a file.

I didn't post the S3Upload function but if anyone is curious, let me know I will share the code for it.

**UPDATE**

```
export async function S3Upload(req, res, callback) {

  const chunks = [];
  let fileType;
  let fileEncodingType;

  const busboy = new Busboy({
    headers: req.headers,
  });

  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    filename.replace(/ /g, "_");
    fileType = mimetype;
    fileEncodingType = encoding;
    file.on('data', data => {
      chunks.push(data)
    });
    file.on('end', () => {
      console.log(`File [${filename}] Finished`);
    });
  });
  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    const userId = UUID();
    const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: userId,
      Body: Buffer.concat(chunks),
      ACL: ACL,
      ContentEncoding: fileEncodingType,
      ContentType: fileType
    }
    S3.upload(params, (err, s3res) => {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback(null, s3res);
      }
    });
  });
  req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

Comment: pls upload the s3 code as well

Comment: @AshishChoudhary Hey! I updated my question and added the s3 code